# How to Style Primary Menu with Active Class

Tags: css

I have been able to style primary menu with hover class, but active class is not working: (www.gehrkeshardwoodflooring.com)

```
.main-navigation {
    color: #b2a79b !important;
}

.main-navigation a:link {
    color: #b2a79b !important;
}

.main-navigation a:visited {
    color: #b2a79b !important;
}

.main-navigation a:hover {
    color: #4d4d4d !important;
}

.main-navigation, #primary-menu a:active {
    color: #4d4d4d !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be confusing the [`:active` CSS pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) and an actual `.active` class. The pseudo class represents an element that is being activated by the user. It is not the active page.

If you want to use the `active` class on the current page, you can use the [`nav_menu_css_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/) filter to add to the nav menu classes.

```
function wpse_nav_menu_css_class( array $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
  if( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) ) {
    $classes[] = 'active';
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 4 );
```

Then, to style the active class,

```
.main-navigation, #primary-menu .active a {
    color: #4d4d4d !important;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use the `current-menu-item` class instead. (Note the hyphens and not underscores)

```
.main-navigation, #primary-menu .current-menu-item a {
    color: #4d4d4d !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes!!! That worked - thank you, Nathan. And I definitely need to learn the difference between those two. Didn't even realize they were two different things. The pseudo class was the only thing I was aware of somehow. I must have been absent that day. Yikes...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a.active in your code, you have *.main-navigation li.current_page_item a*

So, this should fix this:

```
.main-navigation li:hover a { color: #4d4d4d; }
.main-navigation li.current_page_item a { color: #4d4d4d; }
```

Are you agree?

Comment: In theory - yes. But it's not working for me.

Comment: So is .main-navigation, #primary-menu a:active not an active class?

Comment: It works in custom code, but not in WP theme...?